Prisma findMany using where and include fails to filter correctly
Using Prisma 4.15, NestJS 10.0.2, PostgreSQL 14
I am trying to retrieve many entities named transmission, filtering them by the patientId and isDraft properties, and including the patient and constants entities related to them, with a pager.
  async findByPatient(patientId: string, page: number = 1, perPage: number = 2) {
    const transmissions = await this.prisma.transmission.findMany({
      where: {
        patientId,
        isDraft: false,
      },
      include: {
        patient: true,
        constants: true,
      },
      orderBy: {
        createdAt: 'desc',
      },
      take: perPage,
      skip: (page - 1) * perPage,
    });
    return transmissions;
  }

When firing the endpoint that calls this function, it failed to filter on the patientId in the where bloc, and only took the isDraft: false into account when watching the results.
My intuition is that the include block somehow interferes with the filtering as I'm including patients in my results.
I have already tried explicitly using patientId: { equals: patientId } instead of just patientId in the where bloc, to no avail, the results didn't change at all.
Other queries that do not filter using patientId but include patient and constants are working flawlessly.
No other query that filters using one of the included entities are in use right now.
Any workaround to make this query work?

everybody pause, I console.log the patientId, it returned undefined, gonna look into that now

So, the prisma call works fine, the problem was with my controller where I wrote @Param(:patientId') instead of @Param('patientId') so the patientId sent to that function was undefined

All right ! Was wondering where was the issue. Happy coding !
